# Add more item into ListView inside Fragment

Tags: android, listview, fragment, programmatically-created

As ussual I can add more item into ListView in the easy way. But, the problem goes here when my ListView inside of Fragment.

```
public class QuestionFragment extends Fragment {
ExaminationActivity activity;
Question question;

TextView lblQuestion;
ListView listChoice;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    activity = (ExaminationActivity) getActivity();
    question = activity.getCurrentView();
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_question, container, false);
    lblQuestion = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lbl_question);
    lblQuestion.setText(question.getTitle());
    listChoice = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.list_option);

    listChoice.setAdapter(new ChosenAdapter(activity, 0, question.getMutipleChoice(), question.getUserChoice()));
    return view;
}

private class ChosenAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
    Context context;
    ArrayList<String> multipleChoice;
    int selected;

    public ChosenAdapter(Context context, int resource, ArrayList<String> multipleChoice, int selected) {
        super(context, resource, multipleChoice);
        this.context = context;
        this.multipleChoice = multipleChoice;
        this.selected = selected;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_chosen_item, parent);
        RadioButton radio = (RadioButton) view.findViewById(R.id.radio_choice);
        radio.setChecked((selected == position));
        TextView lbl_title = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lbl_title);
        lbl_title.setText(multipleChoice.get(position));
        Log.i("INFO", "chosen " + multipleChoice.get(position));
        return view;
    }
}
}
```

and the error:

10-24 22:48:23.391 31862-31862/com.dragonfly.tracnhiem E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                         Process: com.dragonfly.tracnhiem, PID: 31862
                                                                         android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #15: addView(View, LayoutParams) is not supported in AdapterView
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:539)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
                                                                             at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
                                                                             at com.dragonfly.tracnhiem.activity.QuestionFragment$ChosenAdapter.getView(QuestionFragment.java:65)

Answer (score 0):

A `ListView` that works with an Adapter does not allow adding views, either from code or from XML layout (as in your case).
Instead, you need to add data items to the adapter from your code.  Remember to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()` if data items were added after the view was associated with the adapter.  Take a look at this guide for more information: [Building Layouts with an Adapter](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/declaring-layout.html#AdapterViews)

Comment: I just create my multiple choice application. For each question display I do replace fragment with new data and my xml layout as below:

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" >
<LinearLayout 
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView android:id="@+id/lbl_question"
        android:text="Question One"
        android:textSize="16dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <ListView android:id="@+id/list_option"
        android:background="#CFC"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"></ListView>
</LinearLayout>

Comment: could you give me the best solution display the option in ListView and multichoice is disable, and save selected to database.